# How to apply for loop over Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe and some rows have similar profile id but different values of other columns in different rows. I want to iterate over each profile ID and calculate the difference between two Date_of_Booking for same profile_id but I don't know how to get that.

In short how to calculate the date_of_booking gap per profile_id

Please help[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve], that means no images of code!

Answer (score 2):

Try if at all possible to avoid `for` loops with Pandas.  They are slow and hard to follow compared to vectorized operations.

Try this:

```
df['days_since_last_booking'] = df.groupby('Profile ID')['Date_of_Booking'].diff()
```

Comment: here is error TypeError: diff() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'